# Change metadata in google-cloud-storage python library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python

How to change metadata for the main metadata fields of a file in Google Cloud Storage?
I want to modify the primary metadata fields, such as content-disposition or content-encoding.

My setup:

```
google-cloud-storage 2.3.0.
Google Cloud SDK 359.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.94
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.94
beta 2021.09.24
bq 2.0.71
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2021.09.24
gsutil 5.2
```

However, when I follow the instructions provided in the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python), it only appears to affect custom metadata.

```
def _open_gcs_file_for_write(gcs_blob, mode='w', options=None, content_type=None):
""" Helper function to open a GCS file for writing. """
  headers = {}
  if options or content_type:
    if options:
        headers.update(options)

    if content_type:
        gcs_blob.content_type = content_type

    gcs_blob.metadata = headers
    gcs_blob.patch()


options = {
   'cache-control': 'max-age=3600',
   'content-disposition': 'inline; filename="example.txt',
   'content-encoding': 'gzip'
}
```

After call  _open_gcs_file_for_write, in Google cloud console of bucket storage, I see only changed custom metadata, instead of specific fields:

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example that only changes (patches) the object metadata. Include details on which SDK you are using and its version. Show the error message and results. Don't mention "I tried". Show exactly what you are doing and the results.